# Showing all results also when not present in 2nd optional database

Tags: php

An explaination of how my code works:
I have a pure select on a database that is filled through a different program. I am selecting data to check up on orders. Now I want to give a ready status to the order, which cannot be inserted into the database I am selecting from, so I created a small different database to insert the ordernumber (from the previous selection) into that database and insert a 1. This can be updated to a 0 by pressing the button again.

Now I want to show my orders as the following:

An order can have the status, but doesn't have to have a status.
If it doesnt have a status it should show in the list.
With my current code (below) it only shows orders that are present in the 2nd optional database, I understand why this is happening. But I can't manage to work out a solution to show everything even if an ordernumber is not present in the 2nd optional database.

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $statusorder = $row['ordernr'];  //Ordernumber selected in primary database
    $sqlstatus = "SELECT status from status WHERE Ordernr = '$statusorder'"; //selecting the status from optional database
    $result = $conn2->query($sqlstatus);
    while($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        <insertmyhtmlhere>
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you created another TABLE rather than DATABASE

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one query to get all data. Just use database.Table.column

This will display all order id of table `database1.ordersTable`

```
SELECT db1.id FROM database1.`ordersTable` db1
```

This will display all status of table `database2.statusTable`

```
SELECT db2.status FROM database2.`statusTable` db2
```

Now just combine with LEFT JOIN to show all rows whether it exists or not.

```
SELECT  db1.id, db2.`status` 
FROM  database1.`ordersTable` db1  
LEFT JOIN database2.`statusTable` db2
ON db1.`id` = db2.`status`;
```

Don´t forget to use Condition to filter, in this case, the same order id.

```
ON db1.`id` = db2.`status`;
```

If databases haves different COLLATION you can use this:

```
SELECT  db1.`id', db2.`status` 
FROM  database1.`ordersTable` COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci db1
LEFT JOIN database2.`statusTable` COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci db2
ON db1.`id` = db2.`status`;
```

Here are a [sample fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJ8PFksXiqSBiTEPqeFxF2/0)